# responsive layout is getting broken when zooming

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zooming

I have a page is fully responsive for most of resolution including `width: 480px`. Every elements are perfectly set as they should be. But when I zoom to maximum by using `ctrl+ plus sign`, it zooms to the layout 480px as I can see by firebug, but it does not fit in screen as it was fitted in 480px screen without zoom.

Here's my media query for `480px` screen.

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .inner-main{width:480px;}
   .listing ul li{width:460px;}
   .latest-post-lising-leftside{width:71%;}
   .holder-lattest-gallary{left:25%;}
   .jcarousel li{width:225px;}
   .posts-tab p{width:79%;}
   .footer-inner1, .footer-outer{width:480px;}
   .footer-left{width:460px;}
   .footer-left-down-content{width:240px;}
   .footer-right{width:435px;}
   .jcarousel-control-prev, .jcarousel-control-next{top:131px;}
   .logo { margin-left:0px;}    
   .drop-menu{width:470px;}
   .drop-down-posts{width:139px;}
 }
```

You can see my page here.
http://maitriwebsolution.com/Projects/zayan/html/

I tried giving every elements and div fixed `width` of 480px,but still doesn't fit in maximum zooming. Class `.inner-main` is the effective class for width of whole page, and it has `width:480px` while zooming to max.

Here you can see what I am trying to achieve on this template.Try zooming to maximum by `ctrl+ plus sign` in this site.You can see how every element set to fixed width.
http://pixelgrade.com/demos/bucket/

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: I guess that link is working with resposive based `em` units ... with that unit actually works the zooming responsive.

Comment: so cant we get the result with `px` units? should i start from scratch with `em`?

Comment: As far I know you can't do that with `px` units.

Comment: ok..thanks man..I will wait for other experts like you to take a look, if nothing comes, i will start with `em` as you suggested.

Comment: You can also use a px to em converter, I promise this process is not at all hard. http://pxtoem.com/ <--- I redid my entire sight within ten minutes.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Hi, i tried changing all px to em, but it ruins the whole layout. I think i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you converted all of your pixels?